# How can I unmount user-mounted disks under /media/$username from the command-line?

Tags: 12.10, command-line, mount

In Xubuntu 12.10, I can mount external disks that are attached and they appear under `/media/$username/$diskname`. I can unmount them by going to the desktop, right-clicking, waiting 6 seconds or so, and clicking *Eject Volume* - or by opening `gnome-disks` and clicking on stop on the disk icon.

However, I'd far prefer to simply run `umount /media/$username/$diskname` from the command-line. This currently requires `sudo` rights, or for me to add each disk to the `fstab` - since the whole point of this is automatically mounting previously-unseen disks, that won't work generally.

How can I configure the rights/etc to be able to `umount` automatically mounted disks? I am the right user after all...

Comment: Agreed, this is a duplicate of that question - can someone mark it as such?

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way is to add your user in `/etc/group` under the group `sudo` which will give you the proper right to run `sudo umount /media/$username/$diskname`

If you don't want to enter your password, you can define a special rule with visudo:
`$username ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/umount`

Comment: Thanks - I know how to do that, and I'm actually happy to let my user unmount anything. But it still seems it would be more logical to allow the user to unmount these items as they can do from the UI. What gives the `gnome-disks` application the right to do this without sudo rights for these particular mounts?